# GET request in URL that has params appended by `&` using Retrofit

Tags: android, exception, annotations, httprequest, retrofit2

How to make HTTP GET request in URL that has params appended by `&` using Retrofit in Android?

URL: http://api.com?name=remote&class=TV

Currently, i am using:

```
@GET("http://api.com?name={name}&class={class}")
    Call<CustomType> get(
            @Path(value = "name",encoded = false) String name,
            @Path(value = "class",encoded = false) String class);
```

I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "name={name}&class={class}" 
must not have replace block. 
For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a standard GET request url. Just use `@Query`:

```
@GET("http://api.com")
Call<CustomType> get(
        @Query("name") String name,
        @Query("class") String classs);
```

It will access url:
`http://api.com?name=remote&class=TV`